# terminal freeze after reboot command

Tags: linux, busybox

In my customized embedded linux kernel 4.x.x, when reboot command(implemented in busy box) is given, it freezes the console/terminal and hangs. however linux is still accessible from other terminals.
can any one suggest me what could be the reason of console/terminal freeze ? issue might be related to some terminal related APIs used in busy box implementation but not sure what is the exact cause.
can any one help me to detect possible cause of freeze and any tools or way to detect the cause of this behavior? strace tool is not helping much in this scenario.

thanks.

Comment: Does the device reboot eventually? How long does it take? From other terminals, can you access `dmesg` and/or logs? Anything interesting there?

Comment: no device does not hang ... it is the console where reboot command is fired just freezes and for indefinite time. however i still connect my linux via other newly opened terminals. my problem is console freeze and no reboot from console. however force reboot command is working. no important log during this.

Answer (score 0):

Try apt-get update ,this should fix problems,if not try this:
dpkg --configure -a

apt-get update && apt-get upgrade

apt-get install terminator

terminator is a better terminal btw

Comment: as i said it is a customized embedded linux kernel not the regular one ... i connect my linux system using putty.